# Changing frames of container view controller's view's subview and child view controllers view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(self.treeGraphViewController.view.frame.size.width,
                                 self.menuView.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.menuView.frame.size.width,
                                 self.menuView.frame.size.height);

self.treeGraphViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                     0.0f,
                                                     self.treeGraphViewController.view.frame.size.width,
                                                     self.treeGraphViewController.view.frame.size.height);
```

`menuView` is a subview of the current view controller's view. `treeGraphViewController` is a child view controller of the current view controller. The issue is the `menuView`'s frame is not changing. If I don't change the `treeGraphViewController`'s view's frame, `menuView`'s frame is changing without any issue.

Edit:-

```
---------------------
|  |   | |          |
|  | A |B|       C  |
|  |   | |          |
---------------------
```

C = `self` is the container view controller with B as a sub view.
A = `treeGraphViewController`

C is covering the whole iPad screen. On user interaction(tap on some button on B), A is revealed or moved to the left(origin(A).x = - width(A)).

Comment: Don't change the child controller's frame, just change the container view's frame (or modify its constraints if you're using auto layout), and the child view's frame should follow.

Comment: @rdelmar I have added some more info, I am not using auto layout. The container view is covering the whole iPad screen.

Comment: Disabling auto layout from the interface builder solves the problem.